# Why does the advanced twitter search options not using a radio button

Tags: website-design, forms, usability, search, radio-buttons

https://twitter.com/search-advanced
has the following options

1. Any of the words
2. All of the words
3. Exact Phrase

But the user could make a mistake and enter values for all of them, why didn't they use a radio button across these options.

---

For reference, this is what twitter's advanced search currently looks like:
[image]

Comment: That's not a mistake by twitter or users, that's a feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a little emperical experiement with the twitter advanced search, entering these values:

[image]

The result page gave me exactly that in return:

[image]

From my experiment, I come to the conclusion that the fields can be combined and that a potential radio button group would be all wrong. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I suppose they could emphasize the meaning of the form by putting "and" between the inputs (or before the labels, so that the whole thing runs as a sentence).

Answer (score 4):

They **aren't mutually exclusive options**, and should allow you to search for combinations at the same time.

Let's say that you wanted to search for something about "Joe Bieber", but you didn't want to sort through eleventy million "Justin Beiber" resuts first, you would then exclude any search terms with the word "Justin" in them.

There are many use cases for multiple searches like that, and for that matter **Google has used this method for years**.  I often use multiple constraints in Google searches, and get results that would otherwise be hard to obtain without them.

[image]